# Is backshift required in second conditionals (imagined scenarios) -- 'If I were you, I would go where my friends "were".'

Tags: grammar

I understand that second conditionals are used to express an imagined scenario with a low probability, eg 'if I were you' and 'if I had a billion bucks'.

But is backshift required in this context? Which of the below is grammatically correct?

Edit: let's assume that I'm trying to convey that I would go to the place where my friends ***currently are***, rather than used to be.

> 'If I were you, I would go where my friends ***were***.'

OR

> 'If I were you, I would go where my friends ***are***.'

My gut feeling is that backshift is required. Eg 'If it the raining stopped, we ***could*** go for a walk'. But I have not been able to find an authoritative explanation for this.

Comment: Both sentences are grammatical. Which tense you use depends on where your friends are now. Would you go where they *were* (but are no longer) or where they still *are*? Depending on the intention, one will be wrong, and the other correct. But there is no single rule that can be universally applied outside of context. (And the full context hasn't been provided here.)

Comment: Thanks for your response! So if I'm trying to say I'd go where my friends currently are (rather than used to be in the past but no longer), then backshift is not required? Ie 'If I were you, I'd go where my friends ARE'?

Comment: Why are you asking about backshifting?  What is the context that introduces the need to back shift?

Comment: @JasonYe That's right. If you're talking about where they currently are, then you need to use the present tense.

Comment: What does your last example have to do with it? There you're conjugating "could", which is the same tense as "would" in the earlier sentences. There's nothing analogous to "are" or "were" in that sentence.